# Oops! Something Bad Happened! when visiting my own profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

I am getting this error while visiting my own profile

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
>   and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Are you clicking on your user card on a question/answer, your image in the top bar, or are you using a bookmark you've saved?

Comment: Same problem here! :-(

Comment: Same problem here too, about since 30 mins

Comment: Can't repro, with any of the affected users profiles.

Comment: It seems to be ok now...

Comment: [status-norepro](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-repro)

Comment: What browser? Are you using Ghostery or any content-intercepting/replacing extensions?

Comment: I was just clicking on the profile image on the top navigation